# gmaps4rails not centred and not showing circles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

In my Rails application, the maps markers load perfectly fine, but I cannot get the map to center on the city of Calgary, AB, Canada. I am using the user's location (geocoded by IP), and also I can't seem to get a red circle (depicting range) to appear on the map.

I have the following in my controller:

```
if !request.xhr?
  @json = @students.to_gmaps4rails do |student, marker|
    marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/map/infowindow", :locals => {:student => student}) 
    marker.title "#{student.name}, Grade: #{student.grade}"
    marker.json({:name => student.name, :address => student.full_address, :grade => student.grade, :subjects => student.subjects})
  end
  @mapOptions = "[{ 'map_options' => { 'type' => 'SATELLITE', 'detect_location' => true, 'center_on_user' => true, 'center_latitude' => 50, 'center_longitude' => -114, 'auto_adjust' => true} }]"
end
  @circles = "[{'lng': '#{results['address']['lng']}', 'lat': '#{results['address']['lat']}', 'radius': '#{(results['radius'] * 1000)}', 'strokeColor': '#{ '#FF0000'}'}]"
.
.
.
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml {render :xml => [@subjects,@students,@address].to_xml}
  format.json {render :json => [@subjects,@students,@address].to_json}
end
```

index.haml:

```
= gmaps({"map_options" => {"data" => @mapOptions}, "markers" => {"data" => @json}, "circles" => {"data" => @circles} })
```

Now, ultimately, I'd like to be able to alter the address in circles by using an ajax request.

Comment: why is `@mapOptions` a String? sane question for @circles

Comment: I was trying to access it in faux JSON format, but I'm not sure how to even go forward with this now.